# Why provide types for DOM JSX in @types/react and not in @types/react-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Why provide types for DOM JSX in @types/react and not in @types/react-dom.

If I want to use react-native, isn't there type pollution?

Although this does not affect react-native working.

But how do I get a clean react-native type environment？